# How do I use a headphone or a speaker with a 3.5MM analog audio jack (TRS connector), with a TV that doesn't have an analog output for the audio jack?

Tags: ps3, audio-hardware

I connected my PS3 to my TV through HDMI. I have a headphone and an external speaker, both with a [TRS connector (3.5MM analog audio jack)](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/TRS_connector) that I would like to use with the PS3.

My TV, however, doesn't have an output port for the TRS connector/audio jack, so I am forced to use the TV's speakers. Is there a cable or adapter I can buy that could allow me to use my headphones or the external speakers with the PS3?

My TV's audio/video ports (scanned from the TV manual):

[image]

Comment: What does your TV propose as sound output ? Look at the rear panel, sides of TV or manual. Or give us the TV model.

Comment: @LudoMC I added a scanned image from the TV's manual of its audio/video ports.

Comment: Are you sure these are *all* of the ports on your TV, not just those on the back? A headphone jack is likely to be placed seperately from other ports, e.g. on the side or front of the TV - by not having it on the back of the TV, that makes it more accessible, which is usually desirable in this case - you rarely want to have headphones connected all the time, so it should be accessible, but you generally don't unplug the antenna signal very often, so that can go on the back.

Comment: @Michael Madsen  Yes. I've checked the front and sides of the TV. I even contacted the customer service of the TV manufacturer, which confirmed that there is no TRS connector output.

Comment: 2x HDMI in and no cinch-audio out? That is really weird. What make and model is that TV?

Comment: @Bora It's this: Nikai NTV3203LCDHDN6 http://www.nikai.com/nikai_product_lcd_televisions.asp?p=1p&t=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possible (although awkward) options:

1) connect the PS3 AV Multi Out -> Y-Adapter -> female2female TRS -> your headphones. See details here: http://www.portfolioofpb.com/blog/connect-ps3-xbox-to-ps-computer-speakers-with-surround-sound

2) connect the TV Coaxial audio out -> Coaxial2Analog Converter -> Y-Adapter -> ...
(I found a converter here: http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.44345 )

If you are looking for a better (and more expensive) arrangement, you can buy an AV receiver.

Have fun!

Comment: Can't find any female-female TRS connectors on any local shops, but luckily, I bought a speaker ( http://www.amazon.com/Altec-Lansing-BXR1121-Gaming-Speaker/dp/B000PVH5HU ) that has a TRS Aux in and a TRS out port. With the PS3 AV Multi Out and Y-Adapter, I can now use both the speakers and headphones with the PS3. Sweet!

Answer (score 1):

You need a DAC (Digital to Analog Converter) to convert the coax output from the TV to an analog line output. You can then use a headphone amplifier to drive your headphones. Here is an expensive (but good) approach:

http://www.headphone.com/headphone-amps/headroom-micro-dac.php

http://www.headphone.com/headphone-amps/headroom-micro-amp.php

I have bought other products from Headroom (headphone.com), and have always been happy.

A quick search found a product with those features integrated:

http://www.audiophileproducts.com/fubar4plus

This product is what you are asking for: A headphone amplifier with an integrated DAC and a coax input.

There are certainly other products that do that, the fubar link was just the first result on a search. You can search around to find one that matches your price/performance requirements.