# Connect Xbox 360 Video to HDMI & audio to Subwoofer

Tags: xbox-360, audio-hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can both the digital and analog output on the Xbox 360 be used at once?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/can-both-the-digital-and-analog-output-on-the-xbox-360-be-used-at-once)

I got an Xbox 360 console and connected it to LCD display with HDMI cable and Xbox HDMI converter. My LCD display does not have built in speakers, so I need to connect the Xbox to a subwoofer.

The problem is that when I connect the HDMI converter to the console, the audio cable output jack is covered by the converter.

How can I use both HDMI & audio out at the same time?